# I recently replaced my crankshaft seal on my 95 Infiniti but it’s still leaking oil in the same area, what could be the problem?

Tags: crankshaft, infiniti, oil-seal

recently replaced my crankshaft seal on my 95 Infiniti but it’s still leaking oil in the same area, what could be the problem

Comment: Model of infinity and engine size?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come quickly to mind:

One: that the seal land on the crankshaft is damaged and it still leaks even with a new seal - will need maching or polishing to correct.

Two: that the casting holding the seal is porous and the oil is coming out around the seal - need to replace the casting.

Comment: You missed one: incorrectly installing the new seal. If someone doesn't know what they are doing, it's easy to put the seal back in wrong, which will cause it too leak. Also, if the spring pops off, the seal won't work either. If the seal is installed backwards, it will pump oil out. These last two are really far fetched, but plausible. The first one is a real factor and can happen easily.

Answer (score 1):

A different possibility. Your engine had lots of miles on it. Perhaps oil wasn’t changed on a regular basis. There is excessive wear between the crankshaft and the main bearings. That wear allows for slight movement of the crankshaft, causing an oil leak.

Its also possible that the outside of the crankshaft is worn at the exact spot the seal engages with. Generally this is observable with an inspection mirror.